# Calendar adds data when an item in list is created but doesn't remove its data when an item is deleted from the list

Tags: sharepoint-calendar, sharepoint-list

I have a calendar and a list in SharePoint as when a new item is created the data goes into the calendar but when I delete something from the list the data doesn't goes away from the calendar.
For example:
Event start day/time etc.

I want to know what the issue is and how can I fix this?

Help will be appreciated.
Thank you very much.

Comment: If you create a item in another list in SharePoint then how the data goes into the calendar? Do you have any workflow or something on your SharePoint list?

Comment: Hi Ganesh,
Yes there is a workflow which works as:
Update item in Current Item
then email IT request for Cahnge Form - Approvers
then Create item in ITS Change Calendar(Output to Variable: create1)

Comment: Please see my last edited comment.

Comment: Just a suggestion. Do I have to create another flow for the same purpose which will delete the data if an item has been deleted?
Thanks,

Comment: Or if there's any better way that'll be great.

Comment: Is there any lookup column from change form list in the ITS change calendar?

Comment: There aren't any lookup columns but there are Fields that comes up such as Event cancelled with choice value like Yes or No. Event Type, Category, Modified, Modified by etc etc

Comment: I was thinking of doing something like:
Delete item in Current Item
then Delete item in ITS Change Calendar (Field: Event Cancelled. Value: Yes )

Comment: I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to manually delete linked item in the calendar.
You were creating calendar item based on the run workflow when a new item is created or run workflow when edit item.
I would suggest you to automate the deletion process. Set a flag in the sharepoint list which is set through workflow when the item is ready to be deleted. Add a workflow step which would trigger a delete action based on this column value set by another workflow.
Let me know if you have any questions.
Here is an example for your [reference](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f727af30-1ddf-42e8-9e8f-a1fbfc1146c2/deleting-an-item-fro-a-list-using-a-workflow?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy).